# Substituting Mathematica's solution back into the differential equation doesn't simplify to True

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, replacement

I've recently come across a weird problem. If I have the (cofluent hypergeometric) equation

```
eq = x D[f[x], {x, 2}] + (2 l + 2 - x) D[f[x], x] - l f[x] == 0;
```

Mathematica can solve this easily using the `DSolve` function and gives the answer as two linearly independent soulution

```
sol = DSolve[eq, f, x]
(* {{f -> Function[{x}, C[1] HypergeometricU[l, 2 + 2 l, x] + 
     C[2] LaguerreL[-l, 1 + 2 l, x]]}} *)
```

Which I agree with, now I want to check this result, since I actually got it from somewhere else. But when I put in the code

```
eq /. sol // Simplify
```

I don't get the answer `True` but instead I get

```
E^(x/2) l (1 + l) x^(-(1/2) - l) BesselK[3/2 + l, x/2] == 
  l Sqrt[π] (HypergeometricU[l, 2 + 2 l,x] + 
  (2 + 2 l - x) HypergeometricU[1 + l, 3 + 2 l, x])
```

Why is this the case and how can I validate the solution?

Note that I've tried using `FullSimplify` but this didn't help. I also tried some `Assumptions`, this didn't work and even if it did, Mathematica should be able to "check" the solution even without `Assumptions`, since it gave the answer without any `Assumptions`.

Comment: As far as I see, its an equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eq = x D[f[x], {x, 2}] + (2 l + 2 - x) D[f[x], x] - l f[x] == 0;

sol = DSolve[eq, f, x][[1]]

(* {f -> Function[{x}, 
   C[1] HypergeometricU[l, 2 + 2 l, x] + C[2] LaguerreL[-l, 1 + 2 l, x]]} *)
```

Use [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) in the verification to penalize the use of [`HypergeometricU`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU.html)

```
eq /. sol // FullSimplify[#, ComplexityFunction -> Function[{e}, 
     LeafCount[e] + 100*Count[e, _HypergeometricU, {0, Infinity}]]] &

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = x D[f[x], {x, 2}] + (2 l + 2 - x) D[f[x], x] - l f[x];
```

This answer does not really answer the question, why Mathematica cannot simplify such complex expressions to zero without domain assumptions. That is, and it has to be  left as an open in the general case of multivalued functions like hypergeometric series.

Hypergeometric functions should not be seen as functions in a closed form, they only represent a short notational form, as if for functions with a simple Taylor series like exp the notation hypser(n,x) would be used as a reminder for the exponential by its series. Such notations in the best case give numerical approximations in a complex circle  around an point of analyticity.

Euler and, of course, Gauss were the first to notice, that solutions of differential equations generally produce series solutions with integer spaced products like Gamma and the Pochhammer products in the coeffients of x^n, because each differentiation reduces the exponent by 1 for numerator factors, integration the opposite for denominator factors.

Solve the equation. The generalized Laguerre term may be a polynomial, that will be used for l an integer. If it is a normalizable function, then, by a general theorem on self-adjoint differential operators, a second linearly independent solution cannot belong to the Hilbert space. That candidate is U.

```
sol=DSolve[eq==0,f,x][[1]] 

{f->
  Function[{x},Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1] HypergeometricU[l,2+2 l,x]+
                Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2] LaguerreL[-l,1+2 l,x]]}
```

The Laguerre yields a True

```
0 == eq /. {sol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1}} // FullSimplify

 {True}
```

For the second solution we get a Bessel with a factor, that reveals, how the second solution is  generated in general: try the constant as a function  C[x] f[x]

```
res = Assuming[ x > 0 && l \[Element] Integers , 
  eq /. {sol[[1]] /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}} // FullSimplify]

 l ((E^(x/2) (1 + l) x^(-(1/2) - l) BesselK[3/2 + l, x/2])/Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 
   HypergeometricU[l, 2 + 2 l, 
    x] + (-2 - 2 l + x) HypergeometricU[1 + l, 3 + 2 l, x])

 Series[res, {x, 0, 7}] // FullSimplify

 x^(-2 l) SeriesData[x, 0, {}, 6, 6, 1] + 
      SeriesData[x, 0, {}, 12, 12, 2]
```

To make things easy, ordinary linear differential equations of the second order with x-dependent coefficients can be transformed to have no first order term. The trick is, to implant a x-dependent factor between the D's

```
D[ f'[x],x ]  == a[x]^-1 D[ a[x] f'[x], x ]  == 
f''[x] + D[Log[a[x],x] f'[x]

DSolve[f''[x]== f[x]/x,f[x],x]
```

The aim is, to get rid of the first order derivative by setting

```
repl={f-> (a[#] g[#]&)}
```

and trying to nullify the coefficient  of g'

DSolve[
Coefficient[
x D[f[x],{x,2}]+(2 l+2-x) D[f[x],x]-l f[x]   /.
{f-> (a[#] g[#]&)},
g'[x]]
==0,
a[x],x]//FullSimplify

```
  {{a[x]->E^(x/2) x^(-1-l) Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]}}
```

This type of second order equations with a first order term arise by

```
a[x]^-1 D[a[x]] f'[x] ]
```

and belong to Hilbert spaces with scalar product of gradients

```
Integrate[ f'[x] * a[x] * g'[x], x \el dom] ==
-Integrate[ f[x]  * a[x] *  (a[x]^-1  D[ a[x] f'[x]]), x\el dom]
```

provided, that the products of  f, f', g, or g' at the boundary of dom vanish.

Different boundary conditions generate different operators, Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions, a fact that is the true source of the infinities, if someone is trying to appoximate realistic, interacting quantum  field theories by expansions over the modes of free fields.

In this problem the basis of functions are the two Bessel functions

```
Integrate[ f '[x] *  a]x]  *  g'[x],x\el dom]  ==   
   - Integrate[ f[x] *  a[x] *   a[x]^-1  D[ a[x] g'[x],x] ,x\el dom ]

{f[x] -> -Sqrt[x] BesselI[1, 2 Sqrt[x]] C[1] + 
   2 Sqrt[x] BesselK[1, 2 Sqrt[x]] C[2]}
```